# Using @Parcelize gives Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.Collection.size()' on a null object reference at writeToParcel(Client.kt:0)

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

The Code for my Parcelable Model class is below,

```
@Parcelize
data class Client(
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("accountNo")
    var accountNo: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("status")
    private val status: Status,

    @SerializedName("active")
    private val active: Boolean?,

    @SerializedName("activationDate")
    var activationDate: List<Int> = ArrayList(),

    @SerializedName("dateOfBirth")
    var dobDate: List<Int> = ArrayList(),

    @SerializedName("clientClassification")
    var clientClassification: @RawValue ClientClassification? = null,

    @SerializedName("clientType")
    var clientType: @RawValue ClientType? = null,

    @SerializedName("gender")
    var gender: @RawValue Gender? = null,

    @SerializedName("groups")
    var groups: @RawValue List<Group> = ArrayList()

) : Parcelable
```

Before converting this class to Kotlin, Java code was working fine. Why is it giving Null Pointer since I'm initializing all the List in the constructor of the data class ?

Comment: There are various data types which are nullable in your Client model, like `ClientClassification` `ClientType` `Gender` so although you are initializing lists,  still you can get Null in these Nullable entities.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem as other model classes are working fine. Has this ever occured to you ?

Comment: Yes, usually NPE is been thrown if you are calling some nullable type with this '!!' operator, as I am also using nullable fields in models, but never faced NullPointerException.

Comment: I'm not calling any nullable object using methods. The error is in auto-generated code by @Parcelize Annotation inside writeToParcel method.

Comment: @miPlodder I am also facing this with Parcelize maybe some issue with the kotlin plugin.

Comment: Any solution for the issue?

Comment: @InsaneDeveloper I have searched for the solution and finally end up with https://bladecoder.medium.com/a-study-of-the-parcelize-feature-from-kotlin-android-extensions-59a5adcd5909. Actually there isn't an issue from Kotlin plugin but some fields on my data class are null.